# $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{y_i^2}=1$ and $y_{min} \rightarrow \infty$, prove $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }\sum_{i=1}^n e^{-y_i}=0$

Tags: calculus, analysis

we have two conditions, with $y_{n,i}>0$: $$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{y_{n,i}^2}=1$$ $$min(y_{n,i}) \rightarrow \infty \quad as \;n \rightarrow \infty$$
do we have
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }\sum_{i=1}^n e^{-y_{n,i}}=0$$
I think about this for a long time, only proved $y_{min} \rightarrow \infty$ and 
$n \rightarrow \infty$ are equivalent... I even doubt is this statement correct?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. What are the $y_i$s and $y_{\text{min}}$?

Comment: $y_{min}$ is the minimum of$ {y_i}$

Comment: Do the $y_i$s depend on $n$? Is it something like $y_{n,i}$?

Comment: @abc1m2x3c What does the minimum of $y_i$ mean?  Your notation $y_{min}$ has no room for any dependence on $n$, so what do you mean by $y_{min} \to \infty$?

Comment: Exactly. We have to know how fast the minimum of the $y_i$s goes to infinity depending on $n$. Otherwise, we can choose a minimum, then the number of variables (a huge number), and the last limit is not zero.

Comment: Here's how I would think about it: Choose $S_1, S_2, S_3, \dots$, each $S_n$ a collection of $n$ real numbers $y_n$ such that $\sum \frac{1}{y_n^2} = 1$. For any sequence of $S_n$, if we have that $y_{min} \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ then $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sum \limits_{i=1}^n e^{-y_i} = 0$.

Comment: @Farnight, yeah,$y_i$should be $y_{n,i}$. I see your solution, thank you very much ! I even don't need the first condition actually...

Comment: @Erick Wong yeah,$y_i$should be $y_{n,i}$.  Sorry about that

Comment: @Farnight the first condition is needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\geq5$, then $e^{-x}\leq\displaystyle\frac{1}{x^3}$. Since for large enough $n$, we have $y_\min\geq5$, then:

$$0<\sum_{i=1}^n e^{-y_i}\leq \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{y_i^3}\leq \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{y_\min y_i^2}\leq \frac{1}{y_\min}$$

Since $\displaystyle\frac{1}{y_\min}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, then so does $\sum_{i=1}^n e^{-y_i}$